# Laptop doesn't recognize headphones plugged into the headphone jack since W10 upgrade

Tags: audio, headphones, headphone-jack

Since I upgraded to Windows 10, my laptop no longer recognizes any headphones plugged into the headphone jack. It just plays audio from the speakers - before this, it would switch automatically.

I've installed Realtek high definition audio drivers, Waves Maxxaudio, and even the archived drivers from the original build of the laptop. Nothing works.

The strange thing is, when I reinstalled the drivers, it actually worked the FIRST time I put the headphones in, but then stopped working. I've tried this a few times and it only works the very first time I insert the headphones. After that, it reverts to not recognizing them.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.